# How to imbricate a command inside another command?

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script which allows me to collect information about disks & volumes on Windows servers of the domain where the script is launched:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"' -Properties * |
    Select-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object {
        if (Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1) {
            Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $_.Name -Filter "DriveType=3" | 
                Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceID, 
                    @{Name="Size /GB";Expression={[math]::Round($($_.Size / 1GB), 2)}},
                    @{Name="Free /GB";Expression={[math]::Round($($_.Freespace / 1GB), 2)}},
                    @{Name="Free %";Expression={[math]::Round($($_.Freespace/$_.Size)*100, 1)}}
        } else {
            Write-Nost $_.Name " Connection Error"
        }
    } |
    sort PSComputerName |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I get the following result:

```
SRV01  Connection Error
SRV02  Connection Error

PSComputerName  DeviceID     Size /GB  Free /GB  Free %
--------------  -------- ------------ --------- -------
SERVER03        C:             125,51    105,59    84,1
SERVER04        C:              24,83      7,38    29,7
SERVER05        E:              14,65      7,36    50,2
SERVER06        C:              49,66     29,28      59
```

I want to add an additional column with the OS for each server.
I would like this column to be in second position, after the "PSComputerName" column. How can I get this result?
I think I use a nested command by adding a `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object caption` in the `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk ...`, but I don't know which syntax to use and how to imbricate a command in another command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use -properties *... it's going to retrieve every single populated property which you don't need in this script.

`Get-ADComputer` has an `operatingsystem` property.

Not tested:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"' -Properties OperatingSystem  | ForEach-Object {
    $OS = $_.OperatingSystem
    If (Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet){
        Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $_.Name -Filter "DriveType=3" | 
        Select-Object pscomputername, @{Name="OS";Expression={$OS}} ,DeviceID,              
            @{Name="Size /GB";Expression={[math]::Round($($_.size / 1GB), 2)}}, 
            @{Name="Free /GB";Expression={[math]::Round($($_.freespace / 1GB), 2)}},
            @{Name="Free %";Expression={[math]::Round($($_.Freespace/$_.Size)*100, 1)}}
    }
    else {
        Write-host $_.Name " Connection Error"
    }
} | sort pscomputername | Format-Table -AutoSize
```